# Directly binding a BitmapImage created inside a class bound to a ListBox in WPF, possible?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I am adding object directly to a ListBox, and inside this class, I've got a BitmapImage object.
I'm using an ItemTemplate :

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ElementIcon}"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ElementName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And I directly add object of this class :

```vb
Public Class ExplorerClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Property ElementType As String = Nothing
    Public Property ElementName As String = Nothing
    Public Property ElementContainer As String = Nothing
    Public Property ElementIcon As New BitmapImage
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal WantedElementContainer As String, ByVal WantedElementName As String, ByVal WantedElementType As String)
        ElementType = WantedElementType
        ElementName = WantedElementName
        ElementContainer = WantedElementContainer
        Dim str As New MemoryStream
        Dim IWorking As Icon = showIcon(ElementName.Substring(ElementName.LastIndexOf(".")))
        IWorking.ToBitmap.Save(str, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        ElementIcon.BeginInit()
        ElementIcon.StreamSource = str
        ElementIcon.EndInit()
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ElementIcon")
    End Sub
End Class
```

But, there is no pictures showed;
So, my question is : "How can I bind the BitmapImage" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not implementing the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). Take a look at [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx). I'm not sure if this is also a problem but try setting the height and width of the image.

Comment: The size should not matter as the Image will expand in at least one direction when using a StackPanel and resizing keeps the aspect ratio, hence it should take some space.

Comment: Try calling your NotifyPropertyChanged handler after you set the ElementIcon.StreamSource. The NotifyPropertyChanged is usually only called when you set the ElementIcon and since you are reusing the BitmapImage, it is only called once on construction.

Comment: Look at my first post, I edited my class to add what you said but it still did'nt work